# configure NPM version for dependabot

Tags: npm, dependabot, dependabot-script

I'm using dependabot to update my NPM dependencies with the following `dependabot.yml`

```
version: 2
updates:
- package-ecosystem: npm
  directory: "/"
  schedule:
    interval: monthly
  rebase-strategy: auto
```

But dependabot is using a different version of NPM than the one I have installed locally. Is there a way to specify which version of NPM dependabot uses?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to specify the versions to be ignored, if that helps in your case. Imagining you're using a flavor of npm on `10.0.0`, it would look something like:

```
ignore:
  - dependency-name: 'npm'
    versions: ['<10.0.0', '>=11.0.0']
```

Comment: Doe this syntax mean that versions 11 and higher will be ignored?

Comment: In the example above yes, but you can create your own range.

Comment: -- excellent, thx!